# Trouble Setting / Getting SQLite Values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm just setting up the basics of an SQLite table in Android, but I'm failing in storing / retrieving any values. I can't tell whether I'm failing on the storing or the retrieving side - just that I'm not able to return any values. Here is what I am doing:

Right now I have only a single table with two columns (actually three including the id field). Column 1 is the file name and column 2 it its md5 hash value that I want to store. So, if from somewhere in the app, I call this:

```
String fileName = "image.png"
String md5 = "c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0"
MyDB db = new MyDB(getApplicationContext());
System.err.println("setting md5 for " + fileName + ": " + md5);
int returnValue = db.setSDCardFileMetadata(fileName, md5);
db.closeDatabase();
```

Then I should see `System.err.println` outputs as the value is set and retrieved in the corresponding SQLite database methods like this:

```
setting md5 for image.png: c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0
inserting row for: image.png: c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0
Verifying image.png: c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0 ###
```

But instead, what I am seeing it this:

```
setting md5 for image.png: c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0
inserting row for: image.png: c32005e7c4929527ff67727a24430bc0
no matching file found on sd card: image.png
Verifying image.png:  ###
```

See how the getter function isn't finding a matching value? I'm at a loss. It all looks OK to me. Can anyone see my mistake? Thank you!

```
public class MyDB {

    /* The index (key) column name for use in where clauses. */
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    /* Tables and db information */
    private static final String DB_NAME = "MyDB.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String SDCARD_FILES_TABLE = "SDCARD_FILES_TABLE";

    /* The name and column index of each column in the database */
    private static final String FILE_NAME_COLUMN =  "FILE_NAME_COLUMN";
    private static final String MD5_COLUMN = "MD5_COLUMN";

    /* Database open/upgrade helper */
    private static MyDBOpenHelper myDBOpenHelper;

    public MyDB(Context context) {
        myDBOpenHelper = new MyDBOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);    
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

    /* Called when we no longer need access to the database. */
    public void closeDatabase() {
        myDBOpenHelper.close();
    }

    public int setSDCardFileMetadata(String file, String md5hash) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

        newValues.put(FILE_NAME_COLUMN, file);
        newValues.put(MD5_COLUMN, md5hash);
System.err.println("inserting row for: " + file);
        int returnValue = (int) db.insert(SDCARD_FILES_TABLE, null, newValues);

        System.err.println("Verifying " + file + ": " + getSDCardFileMD5Hash(file) + " ###");

        return returnValue;

    }

    public String getSDCardFileMD5Hash(String file) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String where = FILE_NAME_COLUMN + "= ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.query(SDCARD_FILES_TABLE, new String[] {MD5_COLUMN}, where, new String[] {file}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(0);
        }
        System.err.println("no matching file found on sd card: " + file);
        return "";
    }


    private static class MyDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public MyDBOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        /* SQL Statement to create a metadata table for files stored on the sd card */
        private static final String SDCARD_FILES_TABLE_CREATE = "create table " +
            SDCARD_FILES_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID +
            " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            FILE_NAME_COLUMN + " text not null, " +
            MD5_COLUMN + " text not null);";

        /* Create the new database */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SDCARD_FILES_TABLE_CREATE);
            System.err.println(SDCARD_FILES_TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + SDCARD_FILES_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `getCount() == 1` will fail when you have run your app more than once.

Comment: You're right. It should be db.replace in the setter function. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getSDCardFileMD5Hash` does not correctly check for an existing record; the condition `getCount() == 1` will fail if there are multiple matching records.
You should just use `if (cursor.moveToFirst())`.

To prevent multiple identical records from being inserted into the database in the first place, ensure that you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column you want to check, and instead of `insert`, use [`insertWithOnConflict`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29)`(..., CONFLICT_IGNORE)`.